# bash + how to verify if string/word have some specific charecter

Tags: regex, linux, bash

In my bash script I use the grep command in order to verify if value contain the “-“ character
As the following

```
echo a-b-c-d-f |  grep "-"
a-b-c-d-f
```

or

```
echo version-1-APP-stef-10-1 | grep "-"
version-1-APP-stef-10-1
```

and in my bash script:

```
 [[ ` echo version-1-APP-stef-10-1 | grep -c "-" ` -ne 0 ]] && echo "yes its contain"
```

But this is very ugly way !!!!!!!!!!!

What the alternative in bash to verify if string / word contain specific character as “-“

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need grep here, just glob match will do the job:

```
[[ "version-1-APP-stef-10-1" == *"-"* ]] && echo "hyphen is present"
hyphen is present
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a glob

```
str=a-b-c-d-f    

[[ $str == *-* ]] && echo 'yes'
```